# Export selected set of divs in web page to PDF or Word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ms-word, pdf-generation

Is the following possible? Given a web page with a set of divs with a special id or class, and in this div a title (h1?) and a piece of markup, present a selection list of the div titles witch checkboxes and a button to select all, export the selected divs to PDF or Word.

Example markup:

```
:
<div class="selectable-and-exportable">
  <h1>Chapter One</h1>
  <p>Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div class="selectable-and-exportable">
  <h1>Chapter Two</h1>
  <p>Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum. Lorum ipsum.</p>
</div>
:
```

On click of export button present a lightbox or "in page" popup with:

```
<Select all>

[X] Chapter One
[X] Chapter Two

<Export to Word> <Export to PDF>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I think I better understand the question now. You're asking how to identify and present the fragments of the HTML document, not how to build the PDF/Word file.

Assuming you're using jquery and the jquery-ui-dialog plugin, you might try something like this inside the dialog's `open` method:

```
var jOptions; // this should be a reference to the element in the dialog body where you want to insert the various headings
jQuery('.selectable-and-exportable').find('h1').each(function(){
    var jThis = jQuery(this);
    jOptions.append('<input type="checkbox" name="sections" value="' + jThis.attr('id') + '" /> ' + jThis.text() + '<br />');

});
```

You'll need to write some code for the success method of the popup to actually capture the desired markup based on the set of checkboxes (you shouldn't stuff that markup inside the checkbox `value` attribute).

Comment: Actually I also mean the export to Word and PDF:-) See for example http://www.nicblue.com/gridnic/, the example at the bottom of the page can export to Excel, Word and PDF from client-side code!

Comment: That example just produces a web page designed for print, and then triggers the browser's Print event. If you use a similar approach, you'd still have to solve for Word independently.
If you want users to click a button and receive a downloadable file, you will need to use back-end code to produce the desired format – and in that case, dropping markup into e.g. a PDF won't give you the results you want because viewers for other document formats don't incorporate browser rendering engines, nor are they designed to implement the same formatting conventions.

Comment: you should do generating the pdf on the back side (using java + servlet with a third party library for example itext)